# Ошибка в jar файле, poi , excel

Tags: java, excel, jar, apache-poi

После создания jar файла , перестаёт работать функция "создание отчёта". До собирания в jar всё работает отлично.

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook***
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook***

poi3:

- poi-3.12-20150511.jar
- poi-examples-3.12-20150511.jar
- poi-excelant-3.12-20150511.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.12-20150511.jar

---

Удалил и по новой добавил все jar-файлы, создал новый артифакт, и помогло.

Comment: библиотеки все включили?

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev, Ну да, если бы они не были подключены , то программа бы и из среды не запускалась бы. На сколько я понимаю..

Comment: 1) тогда покажите список библиотек которые вы подключаете и 2) какое расширение вы используете. xls или xlsx

Comment: <path refid="library.com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.classpath"/>
    <path refid="library.antlr-2.7.7.classpath"/>
    <path refid="library.poi-3.classpath"/>

Comment: 2) HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("1.xls");

Comment: добавьте библиотеку xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar должно помоч

Comment: а как вы собирали jar?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ при помощи ant.

Comment: покажите ваш файл manifest.mf

Comment: там ничего кроме версии манифеста и мейн класса не прописано. Проблема решилась подключением xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar и пересобиранием артифакта, не уверен что именно помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это обычно происходит когда в компиляции и runtime используются различные библиотека.

**И еще одно вещь. библиотека `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar` который вы должны включить в `runtime`.**

P.S. в вопрос добавте пожалуйста список библиотек POI которые вы используете

poi-3.12-20150511.jar

poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar

xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

log4j-1.2.17.jar

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на конец лога об ошибке, откуда там взялся пробел? 
***Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFW
orkbook***

Может это и есть ваша проблема? 
Если же нет, отредактируйте пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: Ну с этими jar-никами я ничего не делал, они же работают в среде?!

Comment: Проверил ещё раз, в логе и правда есть пробел. Откуда он взялся и как это исправить?

Comment: Используйте поиск по несобранному проекту и поищите HSSFW или orkbook и удалите пробел

Comment: Вероятней всего в какой-то строке при конкатенации имени класса вы случайно использовали пробел, найдёте где и проблема уйдет, иначе проект не собрался бы корректно. ИМХО

Comment: Михаил не забывайте пожалуйста нажимать на стрелочку вверх если ответ был вам полезен

Comment: После поиска , ничего не нашёл и посмотрев в командную строку, понял что это просто так переносит. Пробела там никакого нет. Проблема не решена(

Comment: Немного непонятно что значит так переносит, сброс на новую строку не может добавлять пробел. Текст ошибки всегда фиксирован. У вашего проекта много классов которые оканчиваются на orkbook?

Comment: Такого класса вообще нет , и созвучных ему тоже). Ну не считая конечно подключённых jar-файлов

Comment: Можно ли посмотреть весь лог ошибки?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8XKSTs3HiDPaWlQUUUzRXBmY0E/view

Comment: И правда проблема не в пробеле, есть подозрение что что то не так с импортами, но вряд ли я смогу вам помочь с этим